# Computed Properties in Prism

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

What is the best way of doing computed properties in the Prism MVVM framework? I've got a `Xamarin.Forms` app with the following properties on a VM:

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _title, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Message);
    }
}

private string _name = "John";
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _name, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Message);
    }
}

public string Message
{
    get { return String.Format("{0},{1}", Name, Title); }
}
```

The code works just fine. However, the Prism library is warning me on the `OnPropertyChanged` statements to use `RaisePropertyChanged` which will avoid the use of magic strings and that OnPropertyChanged with an expression is less efficient.

Is there some other method to notify the view to re-read "Message" whenever name or title change?

It got me to thinking maybe Prism has a way to set things up so that "Name" and "Title" don't have to be aware of Message in order for Message to be updated. This would be preferable if possible. What is the "Prism" way of doing computed properties? I cannot find any examples of it in their `Xamarin.Forms` documentation.

Comment: The line `SetProperty(ref _name, value);` and the fact that all view models inherit from `BindableBase` (an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`) already update the UI whenever you update those properties. You never have to explicitly call `RaisePropertyChanged` or `OnPropertyChanged`. Therefore, you need to make your message a property just like Name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to do this the harder way you can do something like the following:

```
public class FooViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _foo;
    public string Foo
    {
        get => _foo;
        set => SetProperty(ref _foo, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FooBar)));
    }

    public string FooBar => $"{Foo} Bar";
}
```

If you want to make your life a little easier, install [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/) and you can just have a ViewModel like the following:

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Fody should give you an empty Weavers.xml, you'll just want to update it to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
    <PropertyChanged EventInvokerNames="RaisePropertyChanged" />
</Weavers>
```

Comment: Actually, just did an internet search and it looks like Fody does work. Thanks for the first code example as well.

Comment: Not a problem. Yes it does work, I use it in all of my projects now.